# Sort a list in reverse order and remove duplicates

Tags: java, list, data-structures

I am trying to sort a list in reverse order and then removing duplicates. I am using the following code.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
     list.add(3);
     list.add(3);
     list.add(2);
     list.add(3);
     list.add(2);
     Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
     System.out.println(list);
     Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(list);
     System.out.println(set);
 }
```

It works fine but the order is again changed when converted to a Set. What to do to preserve the order

Comment: Use a LinkedHashSet

Comment: HashSet does **not** preserve insertion order. It is that simple.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `LinkedHashSet` instead of a `HashSet`.

```
Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(list);
```

Unlike normal sets which have no guarantee of order, `LinkedHashSet`s enforce insertion order.  Since you've already sorted the list, you don't require any of the extra benefits which a `TreeSet` would provide (which orders based on natural ordering or an ordering of your own choosing).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of HashSet use TreeSet , the access time is less O(log(n)) instead of O(1) but it keeps the order of the keys

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html